# $U_1, U_2, ..., U_k$ subspaces of linear space $X$ with same dimensions, prove $X=U_1\oplus V=U_2\oplus V=...=U_k\oplus V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove the following.
Let $U_1, U_2, ..., U_k$ be subspaces of finite-dimensional linear space $X$ such that

$\dim U_1=\dim U_2=\ldots=\dim U_k$

Then there is a subspace $V$ of $X$ for which

$X=U_1\oplus V=U_2\oplus V=\ldots=U_k\oplus V$

I tried the idea to show that, $V$ lies in the intersection of all of the complements of $U_i$, so $V\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{i=k}U_i^c$, and I think that will work in case this interception is not empty. I am wondering if this is a right way, because I am stuck with proving that it's not empty, so would be thankful for any hint or direction.

Comment: What's the scalar field? For finite scalar fields, the union of finitely many proper subspaces can still be the entire space.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are working in an infinite field K (real numbers for ex) and a finite dimensional space.
You probably know that if $\cup_{i\in I} U_i=X$ then $\exists i$ such that $U_i=X$.
(If the field is finite this holds true if $k$ is less than the cardinality of the field).

So the set $\Gamma=\{G$ subspaces of X such that $U_i\cap G=\{ 0\}$ for all $i\}$ is non empty ($\{0\}$ works).

Let's denote $G\in\Gamma$ of maximal dimensionality.

Now, $r$ being the dimension of the $U_i$, if $r+\dim G<\dim X$ the subspaces $U_i\oplus G$ are strict subspaces of X (ie  $U_i\oplus G\neq X$).

Because of the first paragraph, there exist $x\in X$ such that for all $i$ $x\not\in U_i\oplus G$.

But then $G'=G\oplus K x$ is a direct sum with $\dim G'>\dim G$ and $G'\in\Gamma$ which is in contradiction with the definition of G (max dimensionality).

Then $r+\dim G=\dim X$

You have your result

Comment: What is $E$? ${}$

Comment: Forgot to modify this one. Corrected

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting the remaining typo "$E$ instead of $X$" because someone pointed it out from a linked question.